# How do I take javascript identical functions and make then into a reusable function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I just need to replace these 18 functions with one functions that does the same thing. I've tried several things but an unable to do it with all the loops inside.  I've show you 2 of the 18 to demonstrate the differences. Each td has a specific class assigned to it so it appends the html to the right spot. Any help would be great.

### HEAD

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getLikesFTB(thisURL) {
        // The IDs to the fan pages to like
        var likeURLs = [thisURL];

        // The base of the URL we will build to query the API  
        var reqURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=";

        // Construct the rest of reqURL using our fan pages  
        for (var i = 0; i < likeURLs.length; i++) {
            reqURL += likeURLs[i];
            if (i != (likeURLs.length - 1)) {
                reqURL += ',';
            } else {
                reqURL += "&callback=?"
            }
        };


        $.getJSON(reqURL, function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < likeURLs.length; i++) {
                $('<div/>', {
                    class: "likes" + likeURLs[i],
                    html: "<div class='tacoBoxText'>" + data[likeURLs[i]].likes.toLocaleString() + " people like this.</div>"
                }).appendTo('.tacoBoxMagicFTB');
            }
        });
        $.getJSON(reqURL, function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < likeURLs.length; i++) {
                $('<div/>', {
                    class: "name" + likeURLs[i],
                    html: "<div class='tacoBoxTitle'>" + data[likeURLs[i]].name.toLocaleString()
                }).appendTo('.tacoBoxMagicFTB');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getLikesCareers(thisURL) {
        // The IDs to the fan pages to like
        var likeURLs = [thisURL];

        // The base of the URL we will build to query the API  
        var reqURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=";

        // Construct the rest of reqURL using our fan pages  
        for (var i = 0; i < likeURLs.length; i++) {
            reqURL += likeURLs[i];
            if (i != (likeURLs.length - 1)) {
                reqURL += ',';
            } else {
                reqURL += "&callback=?"
            }
        };


        $.getJSON(reqURL, function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < likeURLs.length; i++) {
                $('<div/>', {
                    class: "likes" + likeURLs[i],
                    html: "<div class='tacoBoxText'>" + data[likeURLs[i]].likes.toLocaleString() + " people like this.</div>"
                }).appendTo('.tacoBoxMagicCareers');
            }
        });
        $.getJSON(reqURL, function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < likeURLs.length; i++) {
                $('<div/>', {
                    class: "name" + likeURLs[i],
                    html: "<div class='tacoBoxTitle'>" + data[likeURLs[i]].name.toLocaleString()
                }).appendTo('.tacoBoxMagicCareers');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

### CSS

```
.tacoBoxMagicFTB
{
    background-color: White;
    border:1px solid #b695cb;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px -1px 3px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 3px #000000;
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 3px #000000; 
}

.tacoBoxMagicFTB img
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

### HTML

```
    <table id="tacoBox" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="520" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/spacer.png" alt="" class="tacoTableColumnSpacer"/></td>
            <td class="tacoBoxMagicFTB" id="tacoFTB"><img src="images/spacer.png" alt="" height="55" width="1"/><img src="images/tb_feedthebeat.png" alt=""/><script type="text/javascript">getLikesFTB('113078108881');</script></td>
            <td><img src="images/spacer.png" alt="" class="tacoTableColumnSpacer"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/spacer.png" alt="" class="tacoTableColumnSpacer"/></td>
            <td class="tacoBoxMagicCareers"><img src="images/spacer.png" alt="" height="55" width="1"/><img src="images/tb_careers.png" alt="" /><script type="text/javascript">getLikesCareers('94517856739');</script></td>
            <td><img src="images/spacer.png" alt="" class="tacoTableColumnSpacer"/></td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you just change your function to this and start passing the class:

```
 function getLikesFTB(thisURL, class) {
    // The IDs to the fan pages to like
    var likeURLs = [thisURL];

    // The base of the URL we will build to query the API  
    var reqURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=";

    // Construct the rest of reqURL using our fan pages  
    for (var i = 0; i < likeURLs.length; i++) {
        reqURL += likeURLs[i];
        if (i != (likeURLs.length - 1)) {
            reqURL += ',';
        } else {
            reqURL += "&callback=?"
        }
    };


    $.getJSON(reqURL, function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < likeURLs.length; i++) {
            $('<div/>', {
                class: "likes" + likeURLs[i],
                html: "<div class='tacoBoxText'>" + data[likeURLs[i]].likes.toLocaleString() + " people like this.</div>"
            }).appendTo(class);
        }
    });
    $.getJSON(reqURL, function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < likeURLs.length; i++) {
            $('<div/>', {
                class: "name" + likeURLs[i],
                html: "<div class='tacoBoxTitle'>" + data[likeURLs[i]].name.toLocaleString()
            }).appendTo(class);
        }
    });
}
```

You've given us quite a bit to look at for those two functions, but it looks like that is the only difference.  If I missed something please let me know.

Comment: So to call it, I would go :  getLikes(thisURL,'.tacoBoxMagicFTB'); Sorry about the length.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the url as a custom attribute on the `tacoBoxMagic` divs, then lose the suffix on the className and do it all at once:

```
$(function()
{
    $(".tacoBoxMagic[url]").each(function()
    {
        var thisURL = this.getAttribute("url");
        // The IDs to the fan pages to like
        var likeURLs = [thisURL];
        // The base of the URL we will build to query the API  
        var reqURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=";
        // Construct the rest of reqURL using our fan pages  
        for (var i = 0; i < likeURLs.length; i++) {
            reqURL += likeURLs[i];
            if (i != (likeURLs.length - 1)) {
                reqURL += ',';
            } else {
                reqURL += "&callback=?"
            }
        };
        $.getJSON(reqURL, function (data)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < likeURLs.length; i++)
            {
                $('<div/>', {
                    class: "likes" + likeURLs[i],
                    html: "<div class='tacoBoxText'>" + data[likeURLs[i]].likes.toLocaleString() + " people like this.</div>"
                }).appendTo(this);
                $('<div/>', {
                    class: "name" + likeURLs[i],
                    html: "<div class='tacoBoxTitle'>" + data[likeURLs[i]].name.toLocaleString()
                }).appendTo(this);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Your HTML would look something like this:

```
<td class="tacoBoxMagic" url="113078108881" id="tacoFTB"><img src="images/spacer.png" alt="" height="55" width="1"/><img src="images/tb_feedthebeat.png" alt=""/></td>
```

Comment: Sorry to be ignorant, but I not sure how to call that in my code.

Comment: @CSSHell - Wrap it in `<script>` tags and drop it in your `<head>`.  It will be called when the dom is loaded.  You won't need to include script tags inside each `<td>`.  If you pass jQuery a function, it will run that function as soon as the dom is ready.  Notice how all of the code is contained inside a call to jQuery: `$(function() { ... });`.  Just make sure you include your jQuery script tag first.

Comment: Ok...so I did as you said above. I changed the class names to tacoBoxMagic['113078108881'] and it's not working. It gets rid all my CSS class too... I like this solution but I think I am missing something.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Ive also tried this:  <td class="tacoBoxMagic" url="113078108881">

Comment: @CSSHell - `url` should be it's own attribute, not part of the class name.  To explain, the selector syntax you see in my jQuery call indicates that we are looking for elements with a class of `tacoBoxMagic` and an attribute of `url`.  I see how it could look like `[url]` would be part of the class name.  I've updated my answer to include an example of how your html would change.

Comment: @CSSHell - I found a typo in my code.  `var thisUrl` should be `var thisURL`.  See if changing that helps.  (I'll update my answer)

Comment: I've followed what you said but it doesn't seem to be outputting the content from the function. Can I PM you the URL so you can see what it looks like in action?

Comment: I used the updated code. I'm sorry to be taking your time. I do appreciate it.

Comment: I only want to PM the URLs because of the client BTW.

Comment: Dont stress. The other solution worked out. Thank you so much for the help.